# Can not change permission of folder through java code

Tags: java, file, hive, file-permissions

I create a temporary folder and then try to change its permission in my Windows 7 machine. I have admin privileges.

```
public class FilePermissionExample
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        try {

            File file = File.createTempFile("temp", Long.toString(System.nanoTime()));

            file.delete();
            file.mkdir();

            if(file.exists()){
                System.out.println("Is Execute allow : " + file.canExecute());
                System.out.println("Is Write allow : " + file.canWrite());
                System.out.println("Is Read allow : " + file.canRead());
            }


            file.setExecutable(false);
            file.setReadable(false);
            file.setWritable(false);

            System.out.println("Is Execute allow : " + file.canExecute());
            System.out.println("Is Write allow : " + file.canWrite());
            System.out.println("Is Read allow : " + file.canRead());

            if (file.createNewFile()){
                System.out.println("File is created!");
            }else{
                System.out.println("File already exists.");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:
Is Execute allow : true
Is Write allow : true
Is Read allow : true
Is Execute allow : true
Is Write allow : true
Is Read allow : true
File already exists.

Expected:
Is Execute allow : true
Is Write allow : true
Is Read allow : true
Is Execute allow : false
Is Write allow : false
Is Read allow : false

I am facing a similar issue while writing hive test using hiverunner in windows. Can anyone suggest something?

Comment: what return methods setExecutable, setReadable and setWritable? What happens if you remove string with setExecutable?

Comment: They all return boolean. 'false' is being return by all the setters. 
I don't understand your second question. Theses methods take boolean as arguments not string. I haven't used a string

Comment: These operations may fail if OS doesn't support operation. I don't know if windows supports executable files so I suggested that doesn't support and setExecutable method fails all three operations.

Comment: Even if I remove sertExecutable() call, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

From the API-documentation for `java.io.File`:

*"A file system may implement restrictions to certain operations on the actual file-system object, such as reading, writing, and executing. These restrictions are collectively known as access permissions. The file system may have multiple sets of access permissions on a single object. For example, one set may apply to the object's owner, and another may apply to all other users. The access permissions on an object may cause some methods in this class to fail."*

So your os doesn't allow to change the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the permission on an NTFS formatted drive you need to change the permissions via the [AclFileAttributeView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html).

Below quite verbose snippet shows the principal to remove the `write` permission for `authorized users` on a given file.

Assume the user `jane` is owner of the file `fobar.bin` and user `john` has as `authorized user` write permission to it. After running the snippet `john` could not write anymore to the file.

```
static final String AUTHENTICATED_USERS = "NT AUTHORITY\\Authenticated Users";

...

Path file = Paths.get("foobar.bin");
AclFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(
        file, AclFileAttributeView.class);

// show current permissions for authenticated users
for (AclEntry acl : view.getAcl()) {
    if (acl.principal().getName().equals(AUTHENTICATED_USERS)) {
        System.out.printf("current permissions: %s%n", acl.permissions());
    }
}

// remove the WRITE_DATA permission for authenticated users
// get list of current ACLs
List<AclEntry> acls = view.getAcl();
for (int i = 0; i < acls.size(); i++) {
    UserPrincipal principal = acls.get(i).principal();
    String principalName = principal.getName();
    if (principalName.equals(AUTHENTICATED_USERS)) {
        // get the current permissions
        Set<AclEntryPermission> permissions = acls.get(i).permissions();
        // remove WRITE_DATA permission
        permissions.remove(AclEntryPermission.WRITE_DATA);

        // create a new ACL entry
        AclEntry entry = AclEntry.newBuilder()
                .setType(AclEntryType.ALLOW)
                .setPrincipal(principal)
                .setPermissions(permissions)
                .build();

        // replace the ACL entry for authenticated users
        acls.set(i, entry);
    }
}
// set the updated list of ACLs
view.setAcl(acls);

// show updated permissions for authenticated users
for (AclEntry acl : view.getAcl()) {
    if (acl.principal().getName().equals(AUTHENTICATED_USERS)) {
        System.out.printf("updated permissions: %s%n", acl.permissions());
    }
}
```

example output (long lines wrapped)

```
current permissions: [READ_NAMED_ATTRS, DELETE, EXECUTE, WRITE_ACL, \
    WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, DELETE_CHILD, WRITE_DATA, READ_ATTRIBUTES, \
    SYNCHRONIZE, WRITE_OWNER, APPEND_DATA, WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS, READ_DATA, \
    READ_ACL]
updated permissions: [READ_NAMED_ATTRS, DELETE, EXECUTE, WRITE_ACL, \
    WRITE_ATTRIBUTES, DELETE_CHILD, READ_ATTRIBUTES, SYNCHRONIZE, \
    WRITE_OWNER, APPEND_DATA, WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS, READ_DATA, READ_ACL]
```

the permission `WRITE_DATA` has been removed.

Comment: I notice that when you do edit the permissions using this the file explorer shows no permissions set.

Comment: looks like this creates new entry in permission entries, not updating the existing permissions